# Text Area row and column size inconsistency in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, razor, textarea

I have been using razor to generate two text areas,

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { autocomplete = "off", @cols = 25, @rows = 1, disabled = "disabled" })

@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Narration, new { autocomplete = "off", @cols = 25, @rows = 1 }),
```

resulting in the html as below,

```
<textarea autocomplete="off" cols="25" data-val="true" data-val-maxlength="The field Description must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '400'." data-val-maxlength-max="400" data-val-required="The Description field is required." disabled="disabled" id="Description" name="Description" rows="1">acknowledgement description</textarea>

<textarea autocomplete="off" cols="25" id="Narration" name="Narration" rows="1"></textarea>
```

the generated html code from the razor is identical both in Chrome and Firefox, but the sizes of the text area are different ( `167x17 px - Chrome , 204.667×36.15 px in Firefox` )

[image: This is how it looks on the browser]

is there any method to fix this issue or something missing in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

apparently this is an issue with Firefox 
[according to this github issue.](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/issues/505)
Firefox is adding an extra row to the text area. since there is no other way of controlling the rows and columns, best option is to set height and width using css.

Answer (score 1):

Use @class="textbox" attribute and specify height CSS property in textbox CSS class.

```
.textbox{
        height:20px;
}
```

Here browsers default styling gets applied so need to write CSS rule to overcome browser compatibility issue.